# Fetch many to many relation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables as follow:

```
users         roles        users_roles
-id (pk)      -id (pk)     -user_id (fk) references users
-username     -name        -role_id (fk) references roles
-password
```

I have three records in roles column (ROLE_USER,ROLE_MODERATOR,ROLE_TESTER)

The relation between in users and roles in many to many relation.
I have a form field (select box containing roles with multiple select option) which allows administrator to search for users depending upon the selection in select box.

Suppose administrator chooses both ROLE_USER and ROLE_MODERATOR. How can I write a single query to find the users having both this role (exclude users having only one of these roles)

Here is the sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214b8/3

I would like to get the user having both the roles (ROLES_USER and ROLES_MODERATOR). The user must have both the roles

Comment: Edited my answer -- had a typo -- hope this helps.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26ea9/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users_roles 
WHERE role_id iN (1,2)
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = 2
```

Here is some sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a3a4/1).

And if you need to `JOIN` to your other tables:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM users u 
    JOIN users_roles ur on u.id = ur.user_id
    JOIN roles r on ur.role_id = r.id
WHERE r.id iN (1,2)
GROUP BY u.id, u.username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) = 2
```

Comment: @sonam -- sure, which Role Ids you want me to test for?

Comment: @sonam -- actually reviewing your sample data, only 1 user has 2 roles: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214b8/7

Comment: @sonam -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.username,group_concat(distinct roles.name) as role_names
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_roles ON users.id = users_roles.user_id
INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id = users_roles.role_id
WHERE roles.name = 'ROLE_USER' OR roles.name = 'ROLE_MODERATOR'
GROUP by users.id HAVING (role_names = 'ROLE_USER,ROLE_MODERATOR' OR role_names = 'ROLE_MODERATOR,ROLE_USER');
```

You can customize this query to fetch the columns that you want and add the grouping based on your needs.

Even though I am not totally comfortable with this query structure, I have given it as a temporary solution.  I would be great if we get any comment from a MySQL expert.

Comment: i am looking for users which has both or many roles depending upon selection inside select box with multiple select option

Comment: I have edited the query.  But this query is still not perfect.  This query will return the user even if the user has ROLE_USER,ROLE_TESTER roles or ROLE_MODERATOR,ROLE_TESTER roles.  I will try to come up with a better solution.

Comment: I have edited the query.  Please test this and let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks it seems to be working for me but i am going with sgeddes solution which is more or less similar to yours. if there is a problem with above solution, please update me

Comment: Yes I agree. sgeddes solution is better and easy.  I just made mine complicated by overthinking little bit.